# vk.com какая функция отвечает за мигание иконки сайта, когда сообщение приходит вне вкладки?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Нужно изменить/отключить функцию, которая ответственна за постоянную смену значения в адресе `document.querySelectorAll("link")[0].href` на `"vk.com/images/icons/favicons/fav_im.ico?5"` и `"vk.com/images/icons/favicons/fav_im1.ico?5"` в момент, когда вы находитесь в другой вкладке и у вас появились непрочитанные сообщения.

Comment: Лучше наверное иконку скачать, чтобы если там её поменяют, на вас это не отразилось